# Getting variables from for loop

Tags: python

I am calculating the nearest distance of two points (latitude, longitude). My code is as below:

```
R = 6378.0
distsecKM = []

for i in range(len(pLat)):
    lat1 = math.radians(pLat[i])
    lon1 = math.radians(pLon[i])
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(secondaryLat)):
        lat2 = math.radians(secondaryLat[j])
        lon2 = math.radians(secondaryLon[j])
        diffLat = lat2 - lat1
        diffLon = lon2 - lon1
        a = ((math.sin(diffLat / 2))**2) + (math.cos(lat2)) * (math.cos(lat1)) * ((math.sin(diffLon / 2))**2)
        b = 2 * math.atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        dist = R * b
        temp.append(dist)
    distsecKM.append(min(temp))
```

I am getting the smallest distance between point1(lat1,lon1) and point2(lat2,lon2). However, I also want to get the lat2 and lon2 used to calculate the smallest distance and save it to a list perhaps.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming you meant `temp` and `temp2` to be the same.)

Instead of

> ```
> temp.append(dist)
> ```

you can simply

```
temp.append((dist, lat2, lon2))
```

The calculation of `min(temp)` works the same as before, because tuples are sorted in lexicographical order (i.e. by first item, if equal by second item, etc.).

If you don't change anything else, `distsecKM` will then contain a tuple, instead of a single value, which you must unpack, e.g. like so:

```
dist, lat, lon = distsecKM[0]
```

Or if you are using it in a `for` loop:

```
for dist, lat, lon in distsecKM:
    # ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list

```
lat2List = []
lon2List = []
```

and then keep appending values to these lists separately.

```
lat2List.push(lat2)
lon2List.push(lon2)
```